# Background image as anchor icon - positioning left of text

Tags: css

I am using following code to set an icon of anchor:

```
.iconed{
    padding-left:22px;
    background-position: 3px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.iconed.selected{
    background-image:url(images/selected.png);
}

<a href="#" class="iconed selected">Some link</a>
```

That works great when anchor has auto width or/and text-align is set to left.
Is there any way to make this icon appear -5px from text when anchor width is set to 100% and text-align is center? I would like not to use :before pseudo class, but if there is no other way...

**Needs to work on IE9+**

**Wrapping with another element is not a solution**

Answer (score 1):

I think pseudo elements might be your only option here. http://jsfiddle.net/2rRDE/

The first one will push the text to the right because it's part of the normal document flow.

The second one looks like it doesn't but I just applied relative positioning and negative margins to pull the text back into the exact center.

```
    a {
        display:block;
        width:200px;
        border:1px solid orange;
        text-align:center;
    }

    .a1:before {
        content:"☺";
    }

    .a2:before {
        content:"☺";
        position:relative;
        left:-15px;
        margin-right:-15px;
        width:15px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

Edit: Response to comment

Your original post never mentioned the requirement to align vertically. But here is a modified version that is the bare minimum and uses an actual image. http://jsfiddle.net/2rRDE/1/

```
a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid orange;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
}


a:before {
    content:url("http://benjinyap.com/system/asset.png");
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

You can't set the pseudo to a block element. The icon should follow the vertical position of the text. But if you want it to be centered regardless of the line height/height/padding of the anchor, then I don't have an answer for that at this moment.

Comment: Not sure how to use it with image icon split to different one-line css where image file is defined.

Comment: `.iconed:before{
 display:block;
 width:22px;
 height:100%;
 background:red;
 left:-22px;
}` does not work at all... no red square...

Comment: I believe you need to set the content property for pseudo elements to show up at all, even if it's just empty quotes.

Comment: ok, I setup content to '', still height:100% does not work, and when I set it to fixed, icon is not at vertical center and text position is being screwed up. Could you please give a proper example with image icon, as for now your answer is not an answer to my question.